# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'h' was corrupted

Tags: c

```
/**horn clauses**/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>
#define NN 10   
#define Nc1 4
#define Nc2 2
#define Nc3 4
#define NH 100
#define RELAX 100
#define NT 100
#define COMBMAX 100
#define TOL 0.001
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define NEGBIAS -0.0
#define NCHCHECK 5

void main()
{
int c3[Nc3][3], c2[Nc2][2], c1[Nc1], i, j, k, l, y, z, n, m, NS[NN], Nbef[NN], iev, ievn, p, comb;
int NI[NN], NF[NN];
float zM, yM, nrelaxM, nrelaxMM;
float J1[NN], J2[NN][NN], J3[NN][NN][NN];
float Erg1, Erg2, Erg3, E1, E2, E3;
float devG, devHD, devHG, devHL;
float ES;
float Eav;
float min;
float h[NN];
float EavM;
float varians, variansR;
float sp, spR;
float EM, EAM;
float Hamming_Distance, HDG, HDL, HDGlobal, HDLocal;
int change, nchange, nrelax;
float nR, NRE;

FILE *outf;
srand(time(NULL));
outf=fopen("ss.text", "w");

printf("Ideal energy landscape of horn clauses \n\n"); 
fprintf(outf, "Ideal energy landscape of horn clauses \n\n"); 
printf(" no. of neurons : %d\n no. of learning events: %d\n RELAX time: %d\n no. of trials: %d\n COMBMAX: %d\n", NN, NH, RELAX, NT, COMBMAX);
fprintf(outf, " no. of neurons: %d\n no. of learning events: %d\n RELAX time: %d\n no. of trials: %d\n COMBMAX: %d\n", NN, NH, RELAX, NT, COMBMAX);
printf("Nc1= %d Nc2=%d Nc3=%d \n", Nc1, Nc2, Nc3);
fprintf(outf, "Nc1= %d Nc2=%d Nc3=%d \n", Nc1, Nc2, Nc3);
printf("TOL= %f\n", TOL);
fprintf(outf, "TOL= %f\n", TOL);

/**Initialize average energy**/

EavM = 0;
zM = 0;
yM = 0;
ES = -NN*NEGBIAS;
EM = 0;
EAM = 0;
z = 0;
y = 0;
Eav = 0;
HDG = 0;
HDL = 0;
HDGlobal = 0;
HDLocal = 0;
nrelaxM = 0.0;
nrelaxMM = 0.0;
Hamming_Distance = 0;
nR = 0;
NRE = 0;

/**Generating min energy supposed to be**/

/**for first order**/
for(i=0;i<Nc1;i++) {    ES+=-0.5;   }

/**for second order**/
for(i=0;i<Nc2;i++) {    ES+=-0.25;  }

/**for third order**/
for(i=0;i<Nc3;i++) {    ES+=-0.125; }

printf("ES = %f \n\n", ES); 
fprintf(outf, "ES = %f \n\n", ES);

/**loop for random clauses combination**/
for(comb=0; comb<COMBMAX;comb++)
{
/**generate random clauses**/
/**first order**/
for(i=0;i<Nc1;i++) {
stt:
    c1[i]=(int)(((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX)*(float)NN);
    for(j=0;j<i;j++) {  if(c1[j]==c1[i]) goto stt;  }
}

/**second order**/
for(i=0;i<Nc2;i++) {
stt1:
    c2[i][0]=(int)(((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX)*(float)NN);
stt11:
    c2[i][1]=(int)(((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX)*(float)NN);
    if(c2[i][0]==c2[i][1]) goto stt11;

    for(j=0;j<i;j++) {  if(c2[j][0]==c2[i][0] && c2[j][1]==c2[i][1]) goto stt1; }
}

/**third order**/
for(i=0;i<Nc3;i++) {
stt2:
    c3[i][0]=(int)(((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX)*(float)NN);
stt21:
    c3[i][1]=(int)(((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX)*(float)NN);
    if(c3[i][0]==c3[i][1]) goto stt21;
stt22:
    c3[i][2]=(int)(((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX)*(float)NN);
    if(c3[i][0]==c3[i][2]||c3[i][1]==c3[i][2]) goto stt22;

    for(j=0;j<i;j++) 
{   if(c3[j][0]==c3[i][0] && ((c3[j][1]==c3[i][1] && c3[j][2]==c3[i][2])|| (c3[j][1]==c3[i][2] && c3[j][2]==c3[i][1]))    ) goto stt2;  }
}

/**initialize synaptic strengths to 0**/
for(i=0;i<NN;i++)
{   J1[i]=NEGBIAS;
for(j=0;j<NN;j++)
    {   J2[i][j]=0.0;
        for(k=0;k<NN;k++)
            {   J3[i][j][k]=0.0;    }
    }
}

/**derive J1 for first order**/
for(i=0;i<Nc1;i++)
{   J1[c1[i]]+=0.5; }

/**derive J2 for second order**/
for(i=0;i<Nc2;i++)
{   
J2[c2[i][0]][c2[i][1]]+=0.25;
J2[c2[i][1]][c2[i][0]]+=0.25;
J1[c2[i][1]]+=-0.25;
J1[c2[i][0]]+=0.25;
}
/**derive J3 for third order**/
for(i=0;i<Nc3;i++)
{   
J3[c3[i][0]][c3[i][1]][c3[i][2]]+=0.0625;
J3[c3[i][0]][c3[i][2]][c3[i][1]]+=0.0625;
J3[c3[i][1]][c3[i][2]][c3[i][0]]+=0.0625;
J3[c3[i][2]][c3[i][1]][c3[i][0]]+=0.0625;
J3[c3[i][2]][c3[i][0]][c3[i][1]]+=0.0625;
J3[c3[i][1]][c3[i][0]][c3[i][2]]+=0.0625;
J2[c3[i][1]][c3[i][0]]+=0.125;
J2[c3[i][0]][c3[i][1]]+=0.125;
J2[c3[i][1]][c3[i][2]]+=-0.125;
J2[c3[i][2]][c3[i][1]]+=-0.125;
J2[c3[i][0]][c3[i][2]]+=0.125;
J2[c3[i][2]][c3[i][0]]+=0.125;
J1[c3[i][2]]+=-0.125;
J1[c3[i][0]]+=0.125;
J1[c3[i][1]]+=-0.125;
}

/**loop to generate random numbers**/
ievn=0;
for(iev=0;iev<NH;iev++)
{   sth:
ievn++;
for(j=0;j<NN;j++)
{   if((float)rand()<(float)RAND_MAX/2.0)
    NS[j]=-1;
    else NS[j]=+1;  }

/**checking clauses satisfaction by events**/
/**for first order**/
    for(k=0;k<Nc1;k++)
    {   if(NS[c1[k]]==-1) goto sth; }

/**for second order**/
    for(k=0;k<Nc2;k++)
    {   if(NS[c2[k][0]]==-1 && NS[c2[k][1]]==+1) goto sth;  }

/**for third order**/
    for(k=0;k<Nc3;k++)
    {   if(NS[c3[k][0]]==-1 && NS[c3[k][1]]==+1 && NS[c3[k][2]]==+1) goto sth;  }
}

/**looping number of trial**/
for(p=0;p<NT;p++)
{   
/**initialize random starting point**/
for(m=0;m<NN;m++)
{   if((float)rand()<(float)RAND_MAX/2.0)
    NS[m]=-1;
    else NS[m]=+1;
    NI[m]=NS[m];    }
/**looping energy relaxation**/
nrelax=0;
nchange=0;
do {    /**calculating h**/
    change=FALSE;
    for(i=0;i<NN;i++)
    {   j=((float)NN)*(((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX));
        h[j]=0;
        h[j]+=J1[j];
        for(k=0;k<NN;k++)
        {   h[j]+=J2[j][k]*NS[k];
            for(l=0;l<NN;l++)
            {   h[j]+=J3[j][k][l]*NS[k]*NS[l];  }
        }
        /**McCulloch Pitts updating rule**/
        Nbef[j]=NS[j];
        if(h[j]>=0) NS[j]=1;
        else NS[j]=-1;
        if(NS[j]!=Nbef[j]) change=TRUE;
    }
    if(change==TRUE) nchange=0;
    else nchange+=1;
    nrelax+=1;
}
while(nchange<NCHCHECK);

/**calculating final state**/
for(m=0;m<NN;m++) { NF[m]=NS[m];    }

/**energy calculation**/
Erg1=0; Erg2=0; Erg3=0;
E1=0; E2=0; E3=0;

for(l=0;l<NN;l++)
{   for(j=0;j<NN;j++)
    {   for(k=0;k<NN;k++)
        {   E1+=J3[l][j][k]*NS[l]*NS[j]*NS[k];
            Erg1=-E1/3;
        }
    }
}

for(l=0;l<NN;l++)
{   for(j=0;j<NN;j++)
    {   E2+=J2[l][j]*NS[l]*NS[j];   
        Erg2=-E2/2;
        Erg2+=Erg1;
    }
}
for(l=0;l<NN;l++)
{   E3+=J1[l]*NS[1];
    Erg3=-E3;
    Erg3+=Erg2;
}

/**calculating global and local minimum**/
if(fabs(ES-Erg3)<=TOL)
{   z+=1;
    for(m=0;m<NN;m++) HDG+=0.5*(1-NI[m]*NF[m]);
}
if(fabs(ES-Erg3)>TOL)
{   y+=1;
    for(m=0;m<NN;m++) HDL+=0.5*(1-NI[m]*NF[m]);
}

/**calculating EM**/
EM+=Erg3*Erg3;

/**calculating average energy**/
Eav+=Erg3/(float)NT;

/**calculating nR**/
nR+=nrelax*nrelax;

/**calculating relaxation**/
nrelaxM+=(nrelax-NCHCHECK)/((float)NT);
}
}

/**calculating average energy for all the combination**/
EavM+=Eav/(float)COMBMAX;
zM+=(float)z/((float)NT*(float)COMBMAX);
yM+=(float)y/((float)NT*(float)COMBMAX);
EAM+=EM/((float)NT*(float)COMBMAX);
nrelaxMM+=nrelaxM/(float)COMBMAX;
HDGlobal+=HDG/((float)NT*(float)COMBMAX*z);
HDLocal+= HDL/((float)NT*(float)COMBMAX*y);
NRE+=nR/((float)NT*(float)COMBMAX);

/**varians**/
varians=(float)EAM-pow(EavM,2);

/**standard deviation**/
sp=sqrt(varians);

/**calculating varians for relax**/
variansR=(float)NRE-pow(nrelaxMM,2);

/**standard deviation for relax**/
spR=sqrt(variansR);

/**calculating hamming distance**/
if(y==0)
Hamming_Distance+=HDGlobal;
else
Hamming_Distance+=HDGlobal+HDLocal;

/**deviation for hamming distance**/
devHD=sqrt(Hamming_Distance-(Hamming_Distance* Hamming_Distance));

/**deviation for global**/
devG=sqrt(zM-(zM*zM));

/**deviation for HDG**/
devHG=sqrt(HDGlobal-(HDGlobal*HDGlobal));

/**deviation for HDL**/
devHL=sqrt(HDLocal-(HDLocal* HDLocal));

/**printing out clauses(one set only)**/
printf("\n Clauses:\n\n");
fprintf(outf,"\n Clauses:\n\n");

for(i=0;i<Nc1;i++)
{   printf("c1[%d] : %d<-.\n",i,c1[i]);
fprintf(outf,"c1[%d] : %d<-.\n",i,c1[i]);
}

printf("\n");
fprintf(outf,"\n");

for(i=0;i<Nc2;i++)
{   printf("c2[%d] : %d<-%d.\n",i,c2[i][0],c2[i][1]);
fprintf(outf, "c2[%d] : %d<-%d.\n",i,c2[i][0],c2[i][1]);
}

for(i=0;i<Nc3;i++)
{   printf("c3[%d] : %d<-%d,%d.\n",i,c3[i][0],c3[i][1],c3[i][2]);
fprintf(outf, "c3[%d] : %d<-%d,%d.\n",i,c3[i][0],c3[i][1],c3[i][2]);
}

/**for synaptic weight**/
printf("for synaptic weight\n\n");
fprintf(outf,"for synaptic weight\n\n");
printf("\n zM   devG    EavM    sp  Hamming_Distance    devHD   HDGlobal devHG  HDLocal devHL   nrelax  spR\n");
printf("%f  %f  %f  %f  %f  %f  %f  %f  %f  %f  %f  %f\n",zM,devG,EavM,sp,Hamming_Distance,devHD,HDGlobal,devHG,HDLocal,devHL,nrelax,spR);
fprintf(outf, "\n zM    devG    EavM    sp  Hamming_Distance    devHD   HDGlobal    devHG   HDLocal devHL   nrelax  spR\n");
fprintf(outf, "%f   %f  %f  %f  %f  %f  %f  %f  %f  %f  %f  %f\n",zM,devG,EavM,sp,Hamming_Distance,devHD,HDGlobal,devHG,HDLocal,devHL,nrelax,spR);


fclose(outf);
}
```

it gives Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'h' was corrupted. can someone help me?

'horn.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\mcm2\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\minor\Debug\horn.exe', Symbols loaded.
'horn.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'horn.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'horn.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'horn.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'h' was corrupted.
The program '[4144] minor.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

this is the full code. sorry if i'd cause any unwanted arguments from anyone..

Comment: Please add a minimal but complete - compilable - example, the code you're showing isn't giving enough information to find the exact problem. (for example, how are `h`, `NN`, `NS`, `Nbef` declared/initialized/used outside this code sample?)

Comment: TBH, I would be surprised if something was not corrupted with code like that.

Comment: I was going to suggest that you debug it but, OTOH, just give up.

Comment: -1 for writing almost incomprehensible multi-dimensional array indexing, with single-letter var names, and then expecting someone else to debug it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a horrible cesspit of fugliness and should just be cast into oblivion.

Comment: _Run-Time Awful Stack Overflow Question #3,042,598 - Your notion of this website was corrupted_

Answer (score 3):

It might be possible that you are accessing your `float h[NN]` array with an index that goes **out of bounds** (correct index values are `0,1,2,3...,(NN-1)`), so you are corrupting the stack around `h`.

You may want to double-check the index values that you are using to access your arrays.

Comment: +1 just for looking at the code.

Comment: -1 for answering questions like this and feeding SO's inevitable and continuing demise.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I think my answer was legitimate and clear, I don't see anything wrong with that. You should be more respectful of people spending some of their time on this site. I might have understood a -1 if I had written something technically incorrect in my answer, but that doesn't seem the case to me. I like this site and spend some of my time trying to positively contribute to it, ...

Comment: ... so I'm not feeding SO's demise, and I strongly reject such a stupid arrogant and false accusation, which I return to you: I give you -1 for your comment, you are projecting yourself: **you** are feeding SO's demise with comments like yours, but thanks God there are people more civil and respectful here. I don't want to waste my time with flame wars, so I end this thing here.
Consider reading [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252070/1629821).

Comment: I'm afraid a random meta post from a random person does not constitute policy. You read this: http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/